# Why does the CSS grayscale filter hide other page elements?

Tags: css, filter, grayscale

Below is code showing three columns with an arrow between each column.

Hover over column one - the arrow head can be seen.

Hover over columns two or three - the arrow head disappears.  Why does it disappear?

```css
.col {
  background: #acf;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 125px;
  height: 200px;
}

.col span {
  color: #f00;
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  left: 100px
}

.col:hover {
  filter: grayscale(50%)
}
```

```html
<p class="col"><span>&#129094;</span></p>
<p class="col"><span>&#129094;</span></p>
<p class="col">&nbsp;</p>
```

https://codepen.io/d-c/pen/rNxyrqz

Comment: My system doesn't have a font able to represent this character, could you also add a screenshot of what you see? Sounds like it's a z-index issue (`filter` does create a stacking context), but to be sure a screenshot would help in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
span {
  z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

add

> **z-index:1;**

to your  **.col span**

And add semicolon to

> left: 100px;

```
.col span {
color:#f00;
font-size:3em;
    position: relative;
    top: 80px;
    left: 100px;
z-index:1;
  
}
```